# Vuetify vertical centering within v-flex element

Tags: vuetify.js

**I'm trying to use a vertical space-between on my components**, or at least use the flexbox capabilities of the framework.

Here is what I want to achieve with an image, the first image represents what I have with my current code and the second is what I want to achieve:

[image]

Here is the basic markup I wrote, I reproduced it on a jsFiddle if you want to play with it: https://jsfiddle.net/tgpfhn8m/357/

```xml
<v-layout row wrap>
  <v-flex xs8>
    <v-card class="red" height="400px">
      Fixed Height Card
    </v-card>
  </v-flex>
  <v-flex xs4 class="purple">
    <v-card class="green">
        First Card
    </v-card>
    <v-card class="green">
        Second Card
    </v-card>
  </v-flex>
</v-layout>
```

**What did I try?**

I tried various methods. The first one was to include a `v-layout:column` into the second column, and apply a `justify-space-between` to it. Without success (https://jsfiddle.net/tgpfhn8m/358/):

```xml
<v-flex xs4 class="purple">
  <v-layout column justify-space-between>
    <v-card class="green">
      First Card
    </v-card>
    <v-card class="green">
        Second Card
    </v-card>
  </v-layout>
</v-flex>
```

I tried a lot of other combinations of elements and properties, without success either.

**What am I doing wrong? Is it even possible to achieve what I want with native Vuetify elements?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to delete the middle `v-flex`.

*You can also use `align-end` on a `v-layout` with the last card in it.*

If you want to keep padding between the two columns, you can add class `pr-x` with `x` a number between 0 and 5 to the first `v-flex`.

To keep the second column filling the height use `fill-height` on the `v-layout` wrapped in a `v-flex`.

[Fiddle with padding](https://jsfiddle.net/tgpfhn8m/361/)

[Spacing doc from Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/layout/spacing)

**Code answer :**

```
<v-app>
   <v-layout row wrap >
      <v-flex xs8 class="pr-3">
         <v-card class="red" height="400px">
            Fixed Height Card
         </v-card>
      </v-flex>
      <v-flex >
         <v-layout column justify-space-between class="purple" fill-height>
            <v-card class="green">
               First Card
            </v-card>
            <v-card class="green">
               Second Card
            </v-card>
         </v-layout>
      </v-flex>
   </v-layout>
</v-app>
```

Comment: I think you are getting close but the second column does not fill the entire restant width: https://i.imgur.com/T42F4u7.png

Comment: That was not asked in the question, but i edited my answer to keep height filling in the second column.

Comment: Thank you, it's perfect now :)

Answer (score 7):

For anyone else who needed this advice:

Use  `<v-layout align-center>` together with `<v-flex fill-height>`

This vertically aligns the children:

```
<v-layout align-center>
  <v-flex fill-height></v-flex>
  <v-flex fill-height></v-flex>
</v-layout>
```